# Plotly dropdown does not present the data when switching options

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to create a plot that shows an international map. So once you hover over each country, you'll see the count of cases, and number of deaths in each country. Also, I want to add a dropdown of 'Description' for the description column, to switch between the descriptions. Right now it shows the correct data for 'All descriptions' only. When switching to other descriptions, it shows the international map with no data at all.

Here's a Glimpse. The columns of the data are: Index(['Case#', 'Year', 'Date', 'Country', 'State', 'Description', 'deaths', 'Tesladriver', 'Teslaoccupant', 'Othervehicle', 'CyclistsPedsivolved', 'TSLAcyclpedsinvolved', 'Autopilotclaimed', 'VerifiedTeslaAutopilotDeaths', 'VerifiedTeslaAutopilotDeathsAllDeathsReportedtoNHTSASGO'], dtype='object') Where a glimpse of the data is:
array([[294, 2022, '1/17/2023', 'USA', 'CA', 'Collisions', 1, '1', '-', '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [293, 2022, '45108', 'Canada', '-', 'Other Causes', 1, '1', '-', '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [292, 2022, '45108', 'USA', 'WA', 'Other Causes', 1, '-', '1', '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [291, 2022, '12/22/2022', 'USA', 'GA', 'Other Causes', 1, '1', '-', '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [290, 2022, '12/19/2022', 'Canada', '-', 'Collisions', 1, '-', '-', '-', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)


unique_descriptions = data['Description'].unique()


filtered_data = {description: data[data['Description'] == description] for description in unique_descriptions}


country_counts = {country: {desc: {'count': 0, 'deaths': 0} for desc in unique_descriptions} for country in data['Country'].unique()}


fig.add_trace(
    go.Choropleth(
        locations=data['Country'],
        z=[country_counts[country][desc]['count'] for country, desc in zip(data['Country'], data['Description'])],
        locationmode='country names',
        colorscale='YlOrRd',
        colorbar_title='Count',
        hovertemplate='<b>%{location}</b><br>Count: %{z}<br>Total Deaths: %{customdata}',
        customdata=[country_counts[country][desc]['deaths'] for country, desc in zip(data['Country'], data['Description'])],
        text=[country_counts[country][desc]['count'] for country, desc in zip(data['Country'], data['Description'])],
        textsrc='inside',
        visible=True  # Set the initial trace as visible
    )
)

dropdown_options = [
    dict(
        label='All Descriptions',
        method='update',
        args=[{'visible': [True] * len(fig.data)}],  # Show all traces
        args2=[{'title': 'Cases and Deaths by Country (Description: All Descriptions)'}]
    )
]


for description in unique_descriptions:


    for country in filtered_data[description]['Country'].unique():
        count = len(filtered_data[description][(filtered_data[description]['Country'] == country) & (filtered_data[description]['Description'] == description)])
        deaths = filtered_data[description][(filtered_data[description]['Country'] == country) & (filtered_data[description]['Description'] == description)]['deaths'].sum()
        country_counts[country][description]['count'] = count
        country_counts[country][description]['deaths'] = deaths


    fig.add_trace(
        go.Choropleth(
            locations=data['Country'],
            z=[country_counts[country][desc]['count'] for country, desc in zip(data['Country'], data['Description'])],
            locationmode='country names',
            colorscale='YlOrRd',
            colorbar_title='Count',
            hovertemplate='<b>%{location}</b><br>Count: %{z}<br>Total Deaths: %{customdata}',
            customdata=[country_counts[country][desc]['deaths'] for country, desc in zip(data['Country'], data['Description'])],
            text=[country_counts[country][desc]['count'] for country, desc in zip(data['Country'], data['Description'])],
            textsrc='inside',
            visible=False  # Set the trace as invisible initially
        )
    )


    dropdown_options.append(
        dict(
            label=description,
            method='update',
            args=[{'visible': [True if desc == description else False for desc in fig.data]}],  # Show only the corresponding trace
            args2=[{'title': f'Cases and Deaths by Country (Description: {description})'}]
        )
    )


fig.update_layout(
    title='Cases and Deaths by Country',
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type='dropdown',
            buttons=dropdown_options,
            direction='down',
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            y=1.1
        )
    ],
    geo=dict(showframe=False, showcoastlines=True, projection_type='natural earth')
)

fig.update_layout(height=600)

fig.show()
```

As mentioned. It shows the data only for 'All descriptions'.

Comment: I am not sure what your intentions are as there are no data or current output graphs. Is it possible to post sample data or current output?

Comment: Here's a Glimpse. The columns of the data are: Index(['Case#', 'Year', 'Date', 'Country', 'State', 'Description', 'deaths',
       'Tesladriver', 'Teslaoccupant', 'Othervehicle', 'CyclistsPedsivolved',
       'TSLAcyclpedsinvolved', 'Autopilotclaimed',
       'VerifiedTeslaAutopilotDeaths',
       'VerifiedTeslaAutopilotDeathsAllDeathsReportedtoNHTSASGO'],
      dtype='object') Where a glimpse of the data is:

Comment: array([[294, 2022, '1/17/2023', 'USA', 'CA', 'Collisions', 1, '1', '-',
        '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [293, 2022, '45108', 'Canada', '-', 'Other Causes', 1, '1', '-',
        '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [292, 2022, '45108', 'USA', 'WA', 'Other Causes', 1, '-', '1',
        '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [291, 2022, '12/22/2022', 'USA', 'GA', 'Other Causes', 1, '1',
        '-', '-', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [290, 2022, '12/19/2022', 'Canada', '-', 'Collisions', 1, '-',
        '-', '-', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

Comment: Update your question instead of answering it in the comments.